# Can I translate "still alive" as 还活着?

Tags: translation, character-identification, handwriting

if I have to translate "still alive" can I write it like this 还活着 or are there better ways to say it? I have to use it as  a title of a poem, so it doesn't have a context or a phrase where it should be written in. It's just the simple poetic expression.

A friend of mine wrote it in "cursive" in the image down below, but I don't even know if the first kanji exists. Would you read 还活着?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can. "还"  = "still" ; "活着" = "alive"

Comment: @Tang Ho, sorry I can't answer directly your comment... thank you for your reply :) what do you think about the image? Would you read it or you'd say that those kanji are quite invented?

Comment: 还活着 is fine. Your friend writing is called  行书 or 草书. I can probably identify his writing.

Comment: @dan thank you very much for your reply :)

Comment: general method for answering this type of  Q: search web using ＂E text, 中文＂ or "C text, English＂

Comment: A nitpick: kanji is a Japanese word for Japanese characters, your question is about Chinese language (that phrase doesn't work in Japanese). Chinese characters are called hanzi. They do not all look the same, especially given you're using simplified Chinese. There is no kanji 还。

Answer (score 2):

`還活著` is correct in meaning

But in most cases `仍(然)活著` is a better translation

Comment: In the same spirit: 依然活着 and 依旧活着 are two alternatives.